# Legend is outside the frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = [1, 2, 3], [5, 7, 2]
fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y)
fig.tight_layout() #растягивает графики на всё окно
leg = ax.legend(['legend'], bbox_to_anchor = (1.0, 0.5), loc='upper left',)
plt.show()
```

Legend is outside the frame. I see part of the legend, but I want to see all. How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

This is what `bbox_to_anchor` does:

> Users can specify any arbitrary location for the legend using the
>   *bbox_to_anchor* keyword argument. bbox_to_anchor can be an instance of BboxBase(or its derivatives) or a tuple of 2 or 4 floats. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> loc = 'upper right', bbox_to_anchor = (0.5, 0.5)
> ```
>
> will place the legend so that the upper right corner of the legend at
>   the center of the axes.

So play around with that tuple, for example try `bbox_to_anchor = (0.05, 0.95)`. Or just leave it out altogether, and the legend will be in the upper left corner.

**Edit:** If you want the legend to be out of the subplot, you can try the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = [1, 2, 3], [5, 7, 2]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes((0.2, 0.05, 0.75, 0.9))
ax.plot(x, y)
leg = ax.legend(['legend'], bbox_to_anchor = (0, 0.9))
plt.show()
```

You can tweak the numbers to fine-tune the positions.

Comment: I need to legend was out of schedule, but I want to see legend.

Comment: @user3301310 You mean out of the the "subplot"? But if you use `tight_layout`, there is no room there?

Comment: Yes, when i use tight_layout(), there is no room for legend!

Comment: @user3301310 I edited the answer to show how legend can be added outside of the plot.